# Issue with Splunk PCRE group name

Tags: regex, splunk

I am trying to add a space to the PCRE group name.Not sure how to do so.For ex:

rex field=_raw "Time taken = (?<"TimeInMillisecs">[^\s^\D+]+)

In the above,I need the group name to be "Time in Millisecs".How do I change the above expression?

Comment: what does your event data actually look like?

Comment: No worries.Got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Don't.  Working with spaces in Splunk field names can be problematic.  It's best to use the compressed name and then use a `rename` command at the end of the query to change to the desired display name.

```
rex field=_raw "Time taken = (?<TimeInMillisecs>[^\s^\D+]+)
| rename TimeInMillisecs as "Time in Ms"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I tried doing so,but could not get it to work.Will it look something like this? rex field=_raw "Time taken = (?<"TimeInMillisecs">[^\s^\D+]+)|rename TimeInMillisecs AS Time in Ms| table Time in Ms.Right now, I have a table at the end of the query fo display purposes.

Comment: I added an example to my answer.  Quotes are not used with the group name in a regex, but are used to rename a field to contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you.Got it working with "rename"

Answer (score 1):

A couple of words on your regex: `[^\s^\D+]+` matches one or more chars other than whitespace, `^`, non-digit and `+` chars.

Note that `\D` matches any whitespaces, `^` and `+` chars since they are non-digit chars, so `[^\s^\D+]+` is equal to `[^\D]+`. And as you can see, "any one or more chars other than non-digit chars" is actually the same as "one or more digit chars".

So, to make your regex free from ambiguity, you can use:

```
rex field=_raw "Time taken = (?<TimeInMillisecs>\d+)
| rename TimeInMillisecs as "Time In Millisecs"
```